# How to proof this congruence relation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While looking for a way to calculate last digits of exponential towers of $3$ I stumbled upon this odd little conjecture and can't really find a way to proof it:

For every $k>1$ and $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$ the following congruence relation seems to be true: $$3^{n} \equiv 3^{n\mod 10^k} \pmod{10^k}$$
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : if you write :$n=(n \mod 10^k)+q.10^k$ you can observe that your statement is equivalent to $$3^{10^k}=1 \mod 10^k $$ but this is not really difficult if you know ruler's theorem which states that $3^{4.10^{k-1}}=1\mod 10^k$. Here to conclude we need that $4.10^{k-1}$ divides $10^k$ for $k\geq 2$ but this is not true, and we cannot conclude your conjecture for $k\geq 2$ using only this result.

**Edit:** I'm sorry I made a mistake in this first answer, so you can not go furthermore using only Euler's theorem because it doesn't give us much about the number $3$, Euler's theorem gives the order of a multiplicative group but if we take an element it's order may be smaller than this order so we will have $3^t=1 \mod 10^k$ and $t$ is smaller than $\varphi(10^k)$ that's why this depends essentially in $3$ and not in the the group itself, In a more formal way: we want to prove the the order of $3$ in the group $\mathbb{Z_{10^k}}$ divides always $10^k$ for $k\geq 2$. when we are dealing with this sort of question the best way is induction:

- For $k=2$ this is true $3^{100}=1\mod 100$
- Assume that $3^{10^k}=1\mod 10^k$ or equivalently :$3^{10^k}=1+q. 10^k$ now we have:
  $$3^{10^{k+1}}= (3^{10^k})^{10}=(1+q10^k)^{10}=1+10 (q.10^k)+45 (q.10^k)^2+\cdots $$

And here we just used the expansion of $(1+x)^{10}$ we observe that the rest of terms are higher powers of $10^k$ so they are all divisible by $10^{k+1}$ and we deduce that $$3^{10^{k+1}}=1 \mod 10^{k+1} $$
Here the proof terminates because we proved the result for $k+1$.

This method is very useful in finding the order of some elements in some groups, the well known example is the order of $5$ in $\mathbb{Z_{2^k}}$ which is $2^{k-2}$ (an exercise for funs) and we can deduce using this elementary results that :
$$\mathbb{Z_{2^k}^*}=\left\{\epsilon 5^t \Big / \epsilon=1,-1;t=0,\cdots,2^{k-2}\right\} $$
$\mathbb{Z_{2^k}^*}$ is the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z_{2^k}}$

Comment: But Euler's theorem does not state that $3^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{10^k}$

Comment: yes you're right! it's $4.10^{k-1}$

Comment: I corrected my answer, I'm sorry for the first mistake and I'added an explanation why we can not deduce this using only Euler's theorem this method works for other numbers as I explained.